How can I check if a value is inside a session in Flask and Jinja?
I want to check if a value, for example the 'name' value, exists in a session in a Flask application I made, but it's not working.
Python:


@app.route("/add/<string: name>")

def add(name):

    session["list"].append(name)

    return "Successful"

@app.route("/list

def list():

    cursor=mysql.connection.cursor()

    query="Select * From data where id=1"

    cursor.execute(query)

    data=cursor.fetchone()

    return render_template("list.html",data=data)

HTML:


{% if data.name in session["list"] %}

There is

{% else %}

None

{% endif %}

Even if the data.name value is in the session, it goes into the else block

1.session is a dict. So if you want the value of a key of this dict to be a list, you should initialise it. (session['list'] = [])
2.The closing quote is missing in the route of /list(@app.route("/list"))
3.Make sure to import session and configure the secret_key(probably you would have imported, but not shown in the code)
4.While fetching from database, if data is dict, you should mention {% if data['name'] in session["list"] %} in your jinja2 code. If data is object, you should mention data.name  like {% if data.name in session["list"] %}. Ensure whether it is used properly.
5.To know if value is inside session, add error handling in the code
@app.route("/add/<string:name>")
def add(name):
    try:
        # Initialize session list if not already present
        if "list" not in session:
            session["list"] = []
        
        # Add the name to the session list
        session["list"].append(name)
        return "Successful"
    except Exception as e:
        # Log the error (optional) and provide user feedback
        app.logger.error(f"Error adding name to session: {e}")
        return "An error occurred", 500


I tried all of these and they didn't work.

Thanks for the help. I solved the problem.

If you save a list within the session and do not make a new assignment but add an item to the list, it is necessary to mark the session as modified. This applies to all changes to mutable structures.
@app.route("/add/<string:name>")
def add(name):
    session["list"].append(name)
    session.modified = True
    return "Successful"

Here is a complete example.
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    redirect, 
    render_template_string, 
    session, 
    url_for
)
import random

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'your secret here'

names = ('ben', 'charlotte', 'gerald', 'peter', 'susanne', 'john')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    session['name'] = random.choice(names)
    session['list'] = []
    return redirect(url_for('game'))

@app.route('/game')
def game():
    if not all(k in session for k in ('name', 'list')):
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    name = session['name']
    return render_template_string(
        '''
            {% if name in session['list'] -%}
                You got a match.
                <a href="{{ url_for('index') }}">Restart</a>
            {% else -%}
                Guess the choosen name.
                <ul>
                    {% for n in names -%}
                    <li><a href="{{url_for('attempt', name=n)}}">{{n | capitalize }}</a></li>
                    {% endfor -%}
                </ul>
            {% endif -%}
            <p>{{ session['list'] | count }} attempts played.</p>
        ''', 
        names=names, 
        name=name   
    )

@app.route('/attempt/<string:name>')
def attempt(name):
    if 'list' in session:
        session['list'].append(name)
        session.modified = True
    return redirect(url_for('game'))


I tried adding it to the list but the same problem persists.

Thanks for your help. I solved the problem.

@MertCahitYiğit What was the reason?

I entered a number into the table instead of the name value and I think it was saved as an intiger. When I corrected it as a string again, the problem was solved.

@MertCahitYiğit Good to hear you solved it. Have fun with your project.
